# Вставить элементы одного списка в другой с определённым шагом

Tags: python-3.x, list

Здравствуйте, стоит следующая задача:

Есть 2 txt файла (количество строк в каждом произвольно). Необходимо строки из одного списка вставить в другой через определённый интервал, например, через каждые n строк.

```
f1 = open(r'c:\Исходная база.txt')
f2 = open(r'c:\Строки для добавления.txt')
list1 = f1.readlines()
list2 = f2.readlines()
f1.close()
f2.close()
i = 0
n = 2
while i + n <= 10:
    list1.insert(i * n, list2[i])
    i = i + 1
with open(r'c:\результат.txt', 'w') as res:
    for item in list1:
        res.write("{}".format(item))
```

В случае, если задать

```
while i + n <= len(list2):
```

list2 - файл откуда берём строки для подстановки, код работает как надо.

Однако, при

```
while i + n <= len(list1):
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
list1.insert(i * n, list2[i])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Прошу подсказать как реализовать подстановку строк из list2 в случае, если строк в list2 меньше, чем в list1. То есть когда строки в list2 кончатся, подстановка строк должна опять начаться с 0 элемента list2.

```
Исходные данные list1: 1, 2, 3, 4, .., m
Исходные данные List2: a, b, c, d, .., k
Результат должен быть: 1, a, 2, b, 3, c ... при n=2
                       1, 2, a, 3, 4, b, .. при n=3
```

При этом важно, чтобы строки подставлялись именно из list2 в list1. И когда строки в list2 кончатся, они должны опять начать подставляться с 0 элемента.

Comment: Лучше вместо простыни текста покажите исходные данные и что должно получиться :)

Comment: Данные List1: 1 2 3 4 .. m
данные list2: a b c d .. k
Итог: 1 a 2 b 3 c если n=2 или 1 2 a 3 4 b, если n=3

Comment: Так намного лучше :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы элементы по кругу возвращались (начинались с первого по окончанию), можно `itertools.cycle()` использовать.

Чтобы по несколько элементов сразу обходить, можно `zip(*[iterator]*n)` идиому применить.

Чтобы чередовать группы из первого итератора с элементами из второго и вернуть плоскую версию (без рекурсии) и  обрезая ввод по меньшей длине аргументов:

```
import itertools

flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable

def interlaced(groups, items):
    return flatten(itertools.chain(group, [item]) for group, item in  zip(groups, items))
```

Объединяя :

```
n = 3
lines = interlaced(zip(*[itertools.cycle(f1)]*(n-1)), f2)
output_file.writelines(lines)
```

Пример:

```
f1 = iter([1,2,3,4])
f2 = iter("abcde")
it = interlaced(zip(*[itertools.cycle(f1)]*(n-1)), f2)
print(*it)
# -> 1 2 a 3 4 b 1 2 c 3 4 d 1 2 e
```

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
In [1]: l1 = [1,2,3,4]

In [2]: l2 = list('abcde')

In [3]: from itertools import zip_longest, chain, cycle

In [4]: list(chain.from_iterable(zip(cycle(l1), l2)))
Out[4]: [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 1, 'e']
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать так, чтобы вместо "None" опять подставлялось "1"?
Задача именно в этом.

Comment: @Kir можно использовать [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle): `list(chain.from_iterable(zip(cycle(l1), l2)))`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, да, спасибо, я как раз собирался добавить пример...

Comment: @MaxU да не за что :)

Comment: @Kir, добавил соответствующий пример

Comment: @Kir я не вижу как этот ответ случай n=3 реализует.

Comment: @jfs действительно не реализует,посмотрел документацию про zip, в очевидном виде аргумента 'шаг' нет.